# Green screen on totem when playing mp4 files

Tags: 14.04, video, totem, gstreamer, mp4

When I try to launch mp4 video files in Ubuntu 14.04, there is only shown a green screen but no video. The audio is running normally.
I use the standard video application in Ubuntu, I think this is totem and uses gstreamer.

Tried this fix here, but it didn't help: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/fix-mp4-playback-in-ubuntu-1204.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link is about some odd looking fix for Ubuntu 12.x, I think it might even be detrimental on Ubuntu 14.04 (I did not have to do such a thing).

MP4 is the container, check what codec it uses by right clicking -> Properties -> Audio/Video tab: Check container and Video codec

I usually use `VLC`, which can play most formats out of the box, but I just tried to play an MP4 with Quicktime container and H.264 video codec with Totem. A pop-up told me to install `gstreamer1.0-libav` and some i386 packages, which must be an error (this is a 64 bit platform I'm working on).

1. Solution: Plugins

Make sure you have the following packages installed: `gstreamer1.0-libav`, `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`, `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` -- should be installed already and optionally `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`

If that doesn't work, post the container format, audio and video codec and we'll see. Or use VLC ^^

2. Solution: Different output channel

If missing decoder plugins aren't the cause, you can install the `gnome-media` package to run `gstreamer-properties`, where you can test the output and change the output plugin (`X Window System (no XV)` seems to solve this issue for some people.

3. "Solution": VMware player

Since you said you're running Ubuntu in a VMware player instance: There might be some issues with that ([see here](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2330200)).

I don't know a fix for that, but using VLC instead seems to work. Or switching to VirtualBox.

Comment: The properties are the same: Container: Quicktime, Codec: H.264 / AVC. I installed the package `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` this one was missing, but nothing changed. Do I have to reboot or something else?

Comment: Mh, according to http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html , that should have been it. Could type `dpkg -l | grep gstreamer` into a terminal and post the output to some kind of pastebin, e.g., http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Ok, here's the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10447117/

Comment: OK, this is possibly a bug. Could you install `gnome-media` then run `gstreamer-properties` and on the Video tab, click "Test" for Video Output. What do you see? You may try to set the output to "XWindow System (no XV)" and see if the green screen disappears.

Comment: I tried this before. I see a standard video test image, independent of what I choose for output. I installed vlc-player now and it works fine... Totem is still giving me the green screen though.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I am running Ubuntu in vmware player. Could this be possibly causing the problem?

Comment: Oh, yes totally. Bc. gstreamer might want to use HW acceleration and VMs sometimes do funny things. Also, there seem to be some issues with VMware: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2330200
But I can't say much about this and can't test it now. I usually use Virtualbox

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will be using vlc from now on this VM. Your answer helped me clear things up, so heres your check ;)

Comment: Cool thanks. I've updated the answer accordingly.