# Is there a script where I can convert ppt to mp4?

Tags: bash, python, c, c#

I want to convert a .ppt to .mp4 file with a script. Is this possible, if yes how can I start ?

Thanks for Ideas...

I know I can export directly over Microsoft Powerpoint but I want a script which does it by himself.

Comment: IS this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: any os ... have you an idea?

Comment: He or she added the [bash] tag..  At least we can assume it's Linux. XD

Comment: Yeah, there's lots of stuff you can do on any OS. However, the answers provided will only include instructions for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

**First, install the following packages:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install unoconv ffmpeg imagemagick
```

**Next, [convert the ppt to pdf](https://askubuntu.com/a/11134/167115) using the following command:**

```
unoconv -f pdf filename.ppt
```

where you should replace `filename.ppt` with the actual file name of the power point presentation.

**Then, [convert the pdf to individual png files](https://ostechnix.com/create-video-pdf-files-linux/) using imagemagick:**

```
convert -density 400 filename.pdf picture.png
```

Again, replace `filename.pdf` with the actual filename of the pdf file when you run the command. Multiple png files will be automatically indexed by number.

**Finally, run the following command to [automatically convert the png files to an mp4 video](https://ostechnix.com/create-video-pdf-files-linux/):**

```
ffmpeg -r 1/10 -i picture-%01d.png video.mp4
```

This is just a general explanation for the last command. Visit [How To Create A Video From PDF Files In Linux - OSTechNix](https://ostechnix.com/create-video-pdf-files-linux/) for more information. For example, the `1/10` specifies 10 seconds per image. Also, `picture-%01d.png` will work with under 10 image files. For more than 9 but less than 100 files, you would use `picture-%02d.png` instead. For more than 99 but less than 1000 files, use `picture-%03d.png` etc.

---

**EDIT:**

If you get a convert error see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407010/cache-resources-exhausted-imagemagick) or run the following command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/rights="none" pattern="PDF"/rights="read|write" pattern="PDF"/;s/1GiB/4GiB/' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

---

**EDIT EDIT:**

If you are having trouble playing the video, install the following packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-crystalhd gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-espeak gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg gstreamer1.0-nice gstreamer1.0-omx-bellagio-config gstreamer1.0-omx-generic gstreamer1.0-omx-generic-config gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dbg gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-doc gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-doc gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-dbg gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-doc gstreamer1.0-pocketsphinx gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-rtsp gstreamer1.0-rtsp-dbg gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-vaapi gstreamer1.0-vaapi-doc gstreamer1.0-x libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamermm-1.0-1 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
```

Also, I tested this using the totem media player so you might want to try using that player:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0 libtotem-plparser-common libtotem-plparser-videosite libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0 totem totem-common totem-plugins
```

Comment: How can I change the policy because the operation is not allowed if I type convert -density .....

Comment: Ok. Policy done. Problem now is that the terminal is given an error by initializing at output stream .. maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate......and so on

Comment: Is it a [cache error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407010/cache-resources-exhausted-imagemagick)? If so, run `sudo sed -i 's/1GiB/4GiB/' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` and then try again. If you get the cache error again, you can increase like this and try again  `sudo sed -i 's/4GiB/8GiB/' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

Comment: I don´t have the policy problem anymore. I can´t convert to .mp4 because of the error "width not divisible by 2" (5333x3000)

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: width not divisible by 2 (5333x3000)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Comment: Se here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert/1081907#1081907 on how to tame Imagemagicks convert.

Comment: @kemaluluz https://stackoverflow.com/a/60793196

Comment: @mchid I tried but the only think is it doesn´t show me up the video. it converts but nothing happens.

Comment: @mchid ffmpeg -i test1-%01d.png -vf "format=yuv444p,scale:375:500" -c:a copy test.mp4

Comment: @kemaluluz `ffmpeg -r 1/10 -i picture-%01d.png video.mp4` works without error.

Comment: it converts yes but doesn´t show me up the video .. why ?

Comment: @kemaluluz Did you try my command? It works for me.

Comment: I tried now. it converts but doesn´t play it up. It opens vlc but don´t play.

Comment: @kemaluluz I'm not sure. Try a different player.

Comment: I tried now. Only green screen :/

Comment: @kemaluluz Sounds like you need to install [restricted extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) and possibly [these gstreamer packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590578/green-screen-on-totem-when-playing-mp4-files) as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127231/discussion-between-kemal-uluz-and-mchid).

Comment: I tried it now with ubuntu and the problem is it takes some time to convert and afterwards it doesn´t play the video

Comment: @kemaluluz What video player are you using? I tried with the ffmpeg command you used and it didn't play but when using the commands in the answer and the totem video player and it works. Make sure you have the [restricted extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) installed and [these gstreamer packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590578/green-screen-on-totem-when-playing-mp4-files) installed as well.

Comment: I added some commands. It might be a bit of overkill on installing all those gstreamer packages but it won't hurt unless you're lacking disk space.

Comment: @mchid I tried your commands to install the packages but it isn´t working. For example it tells me that gir1.2-totem-1.0:amd64 isn´t a package to install I tried without amd64 it installs but doesn´t help me a lot

Comment: @kemaluluz I changed the install command. Like I said, I tried your ffmpeg command and the video did not play but using my command it did. Please open a new question if the video doesn't play; this is really a separate question. I've tested this on my system and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Somebody should make a program that does all of this. I think I will.